# Array.prototype.every() boolean values

Tags: javascript

I'm confused by this `.every()` behavior.

```
let a = [true, true, true]
a.every(Boolean) //  returns true

let b = [true, false, true]
b.every(Boolean) // returns false

typeof false // returns 'boolean'
```

I can not understand why `b.every(Boolean)` returns `false` . What do i miss ?

Comment: `b.every(el => typeof el === "boolean")` returns `true`.

Comment: @ChrisG yeah, i see now. Thanks

Answer (score 13, accepted):

From [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/every):

> The every() method tests whether all elements in the array pass the test implemented by the provided function.

The `Boolean` callback that you use converts the variable passed to it to a boolean, so `Boolean(false)` will return `false`, which makes `b.every(Boolean)` return `false` as well.

Comment: oh, i misunderstood what Boolean() is for . Thanks