# How to find if one of the items have completed property with value false from an array of objects using javascript and react?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

i want to find if there is atleast one item with completed property with value false from an array of objects using javascript and react.

i have an array of objects like so,

```
const items = [
    {
        id: "32",
        jobs: [
            {
                jobs_id: "32",
                completed: true,
            },
            {
                jobs_id: "34", 
                completed: false,
            },
        ],
    },
    {
        id: "31",
        jobs: [
            {
                jobs_id: "30",
                completed: true,
            },
            {
                jobs_id: "33", 
                completed: true,
            },
        ],
    },
    {
        id: "30",
        jobs: [
            {
                jobs_id: "31",
                completed: true,
            }
        ],
    }
]
```

selected_items = {
32: 1,
31: 1,
}

Now i want to check if the items has atleast one object with job completed false for the id 32 and 31 .

basically i have to filter objects with selected_items and then check if the job object completed property value is false.

In the above example selected_items has 32 and 31 ids. so i have to filter items from items array of object with ids 32 and 31 and see if either of their jobs object has completed: false.

in above example we see that item with id "32" has job with job_id "34" has completed: false.

So i am expecting the output to be true if atleast one of the items with ids 32 or 31 has jobs with completed: false. otherwise false.

how can i check this using javascript.

I am new to programming and learning javascript. could someone help me with this thanks.

**EDIT:**
what i have tried?

i know that filtering is possible using filter and array.includes() method.

so if i had selected_items = [32,31] then i could do something like below to get items with id 32 and 31

```
const res = items.filter((item) => selected_items.includes(item.id);
```

but in my case selected_items is object. and this just filters the items for given ids. i want to still check if the items filtered based on ids have atleast on completed: false.

Comment: What did you try so far?

Comment: i have updated my question under edit section. thanks.

Comment: The way you name your object keys is messy , change it into another format list this
const items = [
 {
  id: "32",
  jobs: [
   {
    jobs_id: "32",
    completed: true,
   },
   {
    jobs_id: "34",
    completed: false,
   },
  ],
 },
 {
  id: "31",
  jobs: [
   {
    jobs_id: "30",
    completed: true,
   },
   {
    jobs_id: "33",
    completed: true,
   },
  ],
 },
 {
  id: "30",
  jobs: [
   {
    jobs_id: "31",
    completed: true,
   },
  ],
 },
];

Comment: and I don't really know what you want for this question, You can also leave the example of the answer you wanted. You keep telling `id`. and `id` and `id`

Comment: I'm coming up with an answer, hold on.

Comment: I want it to be evaluated to true if the either of the items with id 32 or 31 has jobs with completed: false otherwise evaluated to false.

Comment: Take a look at the solutions below, I've been outrun.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
const items = [
    {
        id: "32",
        jobs: [
            {
                id: "32",
                completed: true,
            },
            {
                id: "34", 
                completed: false,
            },
        ],
    },
    {
        id: "31",
        jobs: [
            {
                id: "30",
                completed: true,
            },
            {
                id: "33", 
                completed: true,
            },
        ],
    },
    {
        id: "30",
        jobs: [
            {
                id: "31",
                completed: true,
            }
        ],
    }
]

const selected_items = { 32: 1, 31: 1, }

const filteredItems = items.filter(item => Object.keys(selected_items).includes(item.id))

console.log(filteredItems);

const extractCompletedValues = filteredItems.map(item => item.jobs.map(job => job.completed))

console.log(extractCompletedValues)

// returns the array from [[true, false]] to [ true, false]
const booleanList = extractCompletedValues.flat();

console.log(booleanList)

// every will return true if all the values in the Array are true else false
const hasOneNonCompletedItem = booleanList.every(Boolean)

console.log(hasOneNonCompletedItem); // will return false if there is atleast one false
```

Comment: thanks for the answer trying to understand what the .flat().every(Boolean) does.

Comment: edited my answer and added console log for each step .

Comment: This might help - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57565341/array-prototype-every-boolean-values

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
var selected_items = { 32: 1, 31: 1, }
var arrOb =Object.keys(selected_items );
var res = items.filter((item) =>arrOb.includes(item.id));
var flag = false ;
for(let i = 0 ;i<res.length;i++){ 
    if(res[i].jobs.some(ele=>ele.completed===true)){
       flag = true  ;
    break ; 
 }

} 
if(flag){console.log("it contains completed true")}
else{console.log(false)}
```